# Парсинг, Запросы в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо написать программу на `Python`, которая будет выводить ответ, рекомендации, аналогии до текста, который указал пользователь.

> ***UPD:*** Нельзя пользоваться модулем вики

***Пример:***

```py
Ассемблер
```

***stdout:***

```py
Ассемблер это...
```

Как лучше это сделать? Можно хотя бы пример кода.

*P. S.: `Python` учу в ВУЗе всего 3 месяца, а задание не из легких.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел вариант:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup


url = 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python'


source = requests.get(url)
main_text = source.text
soup = Soup(main_text)

data = soup.find('div', {'class': 'mw-parser-output'})
print(data.p)
```

```py
import requests
from PyQt5.Qt import*
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup


url = 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python'


source = requests.get(url)
main_text = source.text
soup = Soup(main_text)

data = soup.find('div', {'class': 'mw-parser-output'})
print(data.p)
app = QApplication([])
showhtml = QTextBrowser()
showhtml.setText(str(data.p))
showhtml.setGeometry(500,500,600,400)
showhtml.setFont(QFont("SansSerif", 20))
showhtml.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Вроде бы у википедии есть нормальное апи. https://wikipedia-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ я с ним не работал, но если оно подойдёт к задаче автора, то предпочтительнее работать с ним, чем завязываться на html-разметку, которая без всякого предупреждения может измениться.

Comment: Точно, а я и забыл :).Все время как надо чего-нибудь найти на сайте начинаю парсить.

Comment: немножко не понял, эта программа через запрос АПИ ищет по ключевому слову информацию? Это то что нужно, если это так

Comment: Нет это программа @nomnoms12 исчет по апи , а я парсил

Comment: Мне нужен такой вариант как у Виктора, только жаль что он не рабочий, просто в условии сказано, что нельзя пользоваться модулем вики

Comment: Нашел вариант :)

Comment: Получил ошибку: this app failed to start because no Qt plattform plugin could be initalized. А в самом питоне так же все красным подсвечено. qt5,request,bs4 установилял через pip

Comment: Вроде исправил ошибку но осталось еще одно: оно выводит много букв с процентами(скорее всего проблема хтмл). Тоесть там есть информация, которая разделена D%

Comment: Ну я думаю вы сами можете это поправить :)
`data.replace("D%","")` Кстати  у меня такого не.
Примите ответ если он вам помог.

Comment: Ответ принял, могу ли я как-то отправить вам скриншот? могу ли я написать вам в личные сообщение?

Comment: Можете написать, что вывела программа у вас?

Comment: В qtextbrowser она вывела:
Python[комм 2] (МФА: [ˈpʌɪθ(ə)n]; в русском языке распространено название пито́н[10]) — высокоуровневый язык программирования общего назначения, ориентированный на повышение производительности разработчика и читаемости кода. Синтаксис ядра Python минималистичен. В то же время стандартная библиотека включает большой объём полезных функций.




А принтом она вывела html

Answer (score 3):

Для таких целей можно воспользоваться [`MediaWiki API`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API).
А для удобства взаимодействия использовать модуль-обёртку [`wikipedia`](https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/).

***Пример:***

```py
import wikipedia


wikipedia.set_lang('ru')


def main():
    query = 'Ассемблер'  # input()

    summary = wikipedia.summary(query)
    print(summary)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
Ассе́мблер (от англ. assembler — сборщик) — транслятор исходного текста программы, написанной на языке ассемблера, в программу на машинном языке.
Как и сам язык, ассемблеры, как правило, специфичны для конкретной архитектуры, операционной системы и варианта синтаксиса языка. Вместе с тем существуют мультиплатформенные или вовсе универсальные (точнее, ограниченно-универсальные, потому что на языке низкого уровня нельзя написать аппаратно-независимые программы) ассемблеры, которые могут работать на разных платформах и операционных системах. Среди последних можно также выделить группу кросс-ассемблеров, способных собирать машинный код и исполняемые модули (файлы) для других архитектур и операционных систем.
Ассемблирование может быть не первым и не последним этапом на пути получения исполнимого модуля программы. Так, многие компиляторы с языков программирования высокого уровня выдают результат в виде программы на языке ассемблера, которую в дальнейшем обрабатывает ассемблер. Также результатом ассемблирования может быть не исполняемый, а объектный модуль, содержащий разрозненные блоки машинного кода и данных программы, из которого (или из нескольких объектных модулей) в дальнейшем с помощью редактора связей может быть получен исполнимый файл.
```